# Windows short path format to long path format

Tags: c++, c, windows, path

Is there a windows API call or some way to translate the paths of the form

```
C:\Progra~1\Users\SomeU~2\
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Users\SomeUser\
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for [`GetLongPathName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980.aspx).

Comment: Is funny. I new it had to be that simple, but after google for a while I simple didn't get that one.